# Count total of leave days on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a table with records of students' leaves with 12 columns for every month of the year and one row for each student.

Each cell keeps the records of the student's leave period for the months in the following format: 3-16, i.e. the student was absent from 3d to 16th day of the month, e.g. 14 days. Some months the student doesn't have any leaves, some months he has.

```
| Jan  | Feb  | Mar  |...
-------------------------
| 3-16 |empty| 4-8   |...
```

How to create a formula to calculate the total number of days the student was absent?

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample design with a working formula you can test out.

`=BYROW(B2:M,LAMBDA(ax,IF(COUNTA(ax)=0,,INDEX(SUM(IFNA(MINUS(--REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(ax),"\d+$"),--REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(ax),"^\d+"))+1))))))`

-

[image]